# Is there a common way to provision network profiles?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I need to provision a number of Linux systems with credentials for wireless networking.  At the very minimum, I need to install a site CA cert.  Ideally, it would also install a unique (signed) client cert, private key, and password.

The Linux systems in question are embedded.  They are running wpa_supplicant directly and don't have network manager.

This seems like a common enough thing that there might be a common way to do this.  Is there?